# Getting error when starting ember server

Tags: ember-cli

I created a new app by:

```
$ ember new app && cd app
$ npm install 
$ bower install
$ ember s
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: ConcatWithMaps: nothing matched [vendor/ember-cli/vendor-prefix.js,bower_components/loader.js/loader.js,bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js,bower_components/ember/ember.debug.js,bower_components/ember-cli-shims/app-shims.js,bower_components/ember-resolver/dist/modules/ember-resolver.js,bower_components/ember-load-initializers/ember-load-initializers.js,vendor/ic-ajax/dist/named-amd/main.js,bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js,vendor/addons.js,vendor/ember-cli/vendor-suffix.js]
at ConcatWithMaps.addFiles (/Users/james/opt/app/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-sourcemap-concat/concat-with-maps.js:90:11)
```

Here is ember -v output:

```
Future versions of Ember CLI will not support v4.1.2. Please update to
Node 0.12 or io.js.
version: 1.13.8
node: 4.1.2
npm: 2.13.4
os: darwin x64
```

Comment: Same problem. Bumped into hour ago. Any luck with solving it?

Comment: My old ember apps are working with no issue.

Comment: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4950

Comment: Seems like it has been resolved: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4950#issuecomment-147721829 working again on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4950 for fix I posted there.